# Compare each of element in list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Is it possible to match two tuple, Compare each of element one by one, and determine where is the change happened.

**Note:** 
runA and runB output is in the loop, so it means it is not hard coded. runA and runB could be range tool01 to tool100 or tool01 only etc, depending to loop result to my query. just simply the tool is in the for loop so the tool no can be more or less.

Example result of my output #1:

```
runA = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '23')]

runB = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '22')]
```

Expected Result #1:

```
print 'there is a changes on tool03'
```

Example result of my output #2:

```
runA = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '23')]

runB = [(u'tool01', '20'), (u'tool02', '21'), (u'tool03', '23')]
```

Expected Result #2:

```
print 'there is a changes on tool01' 
print 'there is a changes on tool02'
```

Example result of my output #3:

```
runA = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '23')]

runB = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '23')]
```

Expected Result #3:

```
print 'there is no change'
```

Any suggestion or basis code, thanks in advance.

**Note:** 
runA and runB output is in the loop, so it means it is not hard coded. runA and runB could be range tool01 to tool100 or tool01 only etc, depending to loop result to my query. just simply the tool is in the for loop so the tool no can be more or less.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use a dict?

Comment: It's certainly possible to write such code, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried? If you've run into trouble with your initial attempts, describe the issues and we'll try to help you.

Comment: yup possible to use dictionary. i'll try. @Blckknght, I just post my concern so that during Im coding there is also help from this session as my backup.

Comment: I add an additional note for my concern because the tool is dynamic can be change depending to the loop is maybe I will make my list as dictionary.

Comment: runA and runB change dynamically, you will have to wait until the loop finished and and keep re-running the loops to find changes?..if this is what you need..then you can add an outer while loop with a condition to keep checking..

Comment: hmm that's a good point ill try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
runA = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '23')]
runB = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '22')]
for i in range(len(runA)):
    if runA[i] == runB[i]:
        print True
    else:
        print False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in runA - 1:
  If runA[i][1] != runB[i][1]:
    print 'there is a changes in ' + runA[i][0]
```

This is assuming 2 things:

> 1. the lists are of equal lengths
> 2. the tuple names have the same indices

As one of your commenters suggest, using a dict would be easier as you can iterate through the keys and access the members with `d[key]`

Comment: I add an additional note for my concern because the tool is dynamic can be change depending to the loop is maybe I will make my list as dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/python
confirm_change=False

runA = [(u'tool01', '21'), (u'tool02', '22'), (u'tool03', '23')]

runB = [(u'tool01', '20'), (u'tool02', '21'), (u'tool03', '23')]

for i in runA:
    for j in runB:
        if i[0]==j[0] and not i[1]==j[1]:
            confirm_change=True
            print("there is a change in",i[0])
if confirm_change==False:
    print("There is no change")
```

Comment: I add an additional note for my concern because the tool is dynamic can be change depending to the loop is maybe I will make my list as dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The next function should do what you need:

```
def matchTuples(runA, runB):
    equal = True
    for i in range(0, len(runA) ):
        if runA[i] != runB[i]:
            equal = False
            print 'there is a change on ' + runA[i][0]
    if equal:
        'there is no change'
```

It iterates over the lists to check if they are equal. If there's is a change, then it prints the name of the tuple that was changed.

At the end, if no changes where detected (that is, if the variable "equal" is still True), it prints 'there is no change'.

Comment: I add an additional note for my concern because the tool is dynamic can be change depending to the loop is maybe I will make my list as dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're saying, but the function should work even if the lists are longer or shorter (assuming both lists have the same length), and even if the tools' names are different..